# How to delete an item from a serialized list?

Tags: javascript, serialization

I make a serialized list (with JQuery) and then want to delete a Parameter/Value pair from the list.  What's the best way to do this?  My code seems kinda clunky to take care of edge conditions that the Parameter/Value pair might be first, last, or in the middle of the list.

```
function serializeDeleteItem(strSerialize, strParamName)
{
// Delete Parameter/Value pair from Serialized list
var strRegEx;
var rExp;
    strRegEx = "((^[?&]?" + strParamName + "\=[^\&]*[&]?))|([&]" + strParamName + "\=[^\&]*)|(" + strParamName + "\=[^\&]*[&])";
    rExp = new RegExp(strRegEx, "i");
    strSerialize = strSerialize.replace(rExp, "");
    return strSerialize;
}
```

Examples / Test rig at http://jsfiddle.net/7Awzw/

**EDIT**: Modified the test rig to preserve any leading "?" or "&" so that function could be used with URL Query String or fragment of serialized string

See: http://jsfiddle.net/7Awzw/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version is longer than yours, but imho it's more maintainable. It will find and remove the serialized parameter regardless of where it is in the list.

Notes:

- To avoid problems with removing items in the middle of an array, we iterate in reverse.
- For exact matching of parameter names, we expect them to start at the beginning of the split string, and to terminate with `=`.
- Assuming there is just one instance of the given param, we `break` once it's found. If there may be more, just remove that line.

#### Code

```
function serializeDeleteItem(strSerialize, strParamName)
{
  var arrSerialize = strSerialize.split("&");
  var i = arrSerialize.length;

  while (i--) {
    if (arrSerialize[i].indexOf(strParamName+"=") == 0) {
      arrSerialize.splice(i,1);
      break;  // Found the one and only, we're outta here.
    }
  }

  return arrSerialize.join("&");
}
```

This fails a few of your tests - the ones with serialized strings starting with '?' or '&'. If you feel those are valid, then you could do this at the start of the function, and all tests will pass:

```
if (strSerialize.length && (strSerialize[0] == '?' || strSerialize[0] == '&'))
  strSerialize = strSerialize.slice(1);
```

### Performance Comparison

I've put together a [test in jsperf](http://jsperf.com/remove-param-from-serialized-list) to compare the regex approach with this string method. It's reporting that the regex solution is 49% slower than strings, in IE10 on 32-bit Win7.

Comment: Thanks. I did consider SPLITing the serialized string, nice to see some code that does the job :) I wonder if there is a faster way to find which array element matches?  Maybe count the number of "&" in front of the parameter in strSerialize rather than looping round the array itself?  
I'm not sure I need support for leading "&^" or "?" but I added them so that function could support queryString and fragments of serialized string

Comment: When thinking about javascript speed, and moreso with Apps Script, it's not enough to count lines of code or loop iterations - you really need to measure it. Why not compare the two approaches in [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/)? Based on other tests I've seen, I expect the string functions have an edge over the regex.

Comment: When I have a moment I will. I've edited the O/P [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Awzw/5/) to preserve any leading "?" / "&"

Comment: @Kristen - Done! I've added the link to the jsperf test in the question.

Comment: Thanks. I had checked the performance of RegEx vs. Array Loop and seen the same thing. Its a lot easier to manipulate serialised parameters once they are in an array too, so I'll adopt that in future, thanks. What I was hoping to find was a quicker way of locating which array element matched (rather than having to loop the array); I had hoped that it would be possible to use a search of the original serialized string to find the offset of the matching parameter and count the number of "&" in front of it, but I gave up looking for a solution as it was taking me too long!

Comment: @Kristen - since the list is unsorted and pretty short, you're not likely to beat the O(n/2) loop. If you are going to do many searches, you could benefit from sorting the list O(log n), say, then doing a binary search O(log n), with a break-even point at approximately 3 lookups in a list of 4 elements. Hardly seems worth complicating the code.